# Array of value from multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I wanna return an array of value from multiple conditions.
Currently formula is set to accept one condition.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgVlBWYKWtT6AEPyRtZmAYdOXBCjYG_B7pdlvCqYq0A/edit?usp=sharing

The desired result is showed in the ad hoc worksheet

Edit : initial problem solved by player0. Thanks !

Previous post

*I'm using curly brace to return an array of value with the IF formula. This works well. I wanted to use IFS function because i wanted to use more conditions.
With a similar table, only the 1st number is returned form the array.
I don't understand why.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgVlBWYKWtT6AEPyRtZmAYdOXBCjYG_B7pdlvCqYq0A/edit?usp=sharing
Thanks !*

Comment: what are those "more conditions" ?

Comment: I've edited my post to display them

Answer (score 0):

delete range E2:L and use this in E2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
 IF((E1:L1=B2:B11)+(E1:L1=C2:C11)+(E1:L1=D2:D11); 
 "1;2;3;4;5;6;7"; ";");;9^9)); ";"; 1; 0)))
```

[image]