# Array of value using array formula

Tags: google-sheets

I wanna return an array of value from multiple conditions, using an array formula.
I manage to make a working formula but without array formula, witch is annoying because of filling conflicts in the worksheet.

[Here is the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pgVlBWYKWtT6AEPyRtZmAYdOXBCjYG_B7pdlvCqYq0A/edit#gid=1581332401)

[Note : current solution developped from this initial thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727557/array-of-value-from-multiple-conditions)

Comment: Hey, when sharing spreadsheets make a copy of the original one, remove any information not related to the question, and share a view-only copy. This makes sure that the spreadsheet is not modified after the question is resolved, so future people can see what the question was about. Also, the spreadsheet you posted can be edited by anyone.

Comment: Can you explain how long to make the sequence for each matching value? it seems like maybe it should count from 1 to 7 each time?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

Use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(IF((F$1:$1&F$2:$2&F$3:$3&F$4:$4)<>"";IFERROR(REPT(";";IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4;{$B$5:$B\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)};2;FALSE);-1)+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4;{$C$5:$C\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)};2;FALSE);-1)+IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4;{$D$5:$D\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)};2;FALSE);-1)+2);"#Batch?  ")&IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$1:$1&"-----"&F$2:$2;{ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Fprod!$H$2:$H);Fprod!$F$2:$F&"-----"&Fprod!$G$2:$G;))\Fprod!$H$2:$H};2;FALSE);"#Species/supplier?");";"));";";TRUE;FALSE)))
```

I'll try to explain my thought process so you are able to make changes or make similar formulas in the future and for reference for other people.

### Basic explanation

I've noticed a few things that will help us make a formula for this problem:

1. In the `Fprod` sheet you have the list of suppliers and species with the weeks.
2. There is only a single list for each batch.
3. Your locale doesn't allow the usage of commas in the formulas. `\` must be used instead

The basic idea of the formula is to get a string defining the columns. It's basically the values on `Fprod` with a padding of semicolons to vertically move it. After that  we want to convert it into columns (similar to how it was used in the other question). For example, if the `CNC` + `shiitake` (batch `2101`) started at week 4, we want to achieve `;;;1;2;3;4;5;6` which then becomes:

| 2101 |
| --- |
| `<empty>` |
| `<empty>` |
| `<empty>` |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |

#### Step 1: Getting the spec for a supplier's species

Having the supplier and the species, we want to get the weeks on `Fprod` (ie. having `CNC` + `shiitake` sould give us `1;2;3;4;5;6`).

To do so, we'll use a [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) to get the correct list for the week. The problem is that we need to check for 2 columns. So the trick is to join both columns with some characters in the middle (eg `-----`) to prevent unexpected collisions. So working on the F column:

```
=VLOOKUP(
  F$1&"-----"&F$2;
  {ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Fprod!$H$2:$H); Fprod!$F$2:$F&"-----"&Fprod!$G$2:$G;)) \ Fprod!$H$2:$H};
  2;
  FALSE
)
```

Let's unpack this, as there are already a lot of things.

Let's start with the second argument, as it's the most complex one. What it does is to make a table (2D array) where the first column is `<supplier>-----<species>` for each entry on `Fprod`, and the second column is the value we want. To make the first column we can use a [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) to add both columns row by row:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(Fprod!$F$2:$F & "-----" & Fprod!$G$2:$G)
```

The second column is simply `H2:H` of `Fprod`.

They are joined as columns. To see how this works try `={1\2}` (usually it's `,` but because of your locale `\` is required). This will generate a result similar to:

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| CNC-----shiitake | 1;2;3;4;5;6 |
| euro-----shiitake | 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14 |
| euro-----pleurote | 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;21;22 |
| Lentin-----shiitake | 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14 |
| Moser-----agaricus | 1;2;3;4;5;6 |
| ----- |  |
| ----- |  |

As you can see we are also generating empty entries. To ignore them, we'll check that the H column of that row is not empty:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Fprod!$H$2:$H); Fprod!$F$2:$F&"-----"&Fprod!$G$2:$G;))
```

Now we can simply use [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) to get the value in the second column. The value we search for is in the same format as the first column. In this case we'll use the F column and generalize later. If you add this to an F column you should see `1;2;3;4;5;6` appear.

It's important to note the last argument, as the data is not sorted and setting it to true or not setting it (it's true by default) would cause problems.

### Step 2: Generating the padding

To generate a padding we'll need to use some [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) to detect at what row is the value. We need 3 of them one for each column. The idea being that in the first column you have the value you need to look up (the batch) and on the second, the number of padding required. It looks like:

```
={$B$5:$B\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}
```

`$B$5:$B` is simply the column B starting at row 5. `ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)` is a trick:
`ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(Ai:Aj))` will return a count list from `i` to `j` inclusive. For example `ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A6))` will return

| result |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 6 |

In this case we need the result to have the same size as the other table so we are forced to use `ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A))` to do so. Because of that the values are too big, so we need to subtract 5, giving us `ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)`.

Join them into a single table and you have where to lookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(F$4; {$B$5:$B\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE)
```

This is very similar to what it was done before. If you add this to `F5` you'll see that it says the offset (# week minus one).

Like I pointed before wee need this for the three columns, but wee need to make sure it doesn't crash. To do that we want set a default value to `-1` if not in the column. This is simple by using [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en).

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4; {$B$5:$B\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1)
```

We cannot use [MAX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013?hl=en) to join them because it cannot be used with [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) because if can use ranges. Because of that we need to get creative, so I added them. This means that there is 2 `-1` and the value; so adding 2 compensates it:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4; {$B$5:$B\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4; {$C$5:$C\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4; {$D$5:$D\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
2
```

Now we only need to use [REPT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134?hl=en) to repeat `;` as many times as we need:

```
=REPT(
  ";";
  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4; {$B$5:$B\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4; {$C$5:$C\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4; {$D$5:$D\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
  2
)
```

### Step 3: Joining them

You may simply join them like you join regular strings. Note that the padding goes first

```
=REPT(
  ";";
  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4; {$B$5:$B\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4; {$C$5:$C\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4; {$D$5:$D\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
  2
)&
VLOOKUP(
  F$1&"-----"&F$2;
  {ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Fprod!$H$2:$H); Fprod!$F$2:$F&"-----"&Fprod!$G$2:$G;)) \ Fprod!$H$2:$H};
  2;
  FALSE
)
```

### Step 4: All the columns in one formula

Now it's a good moment to apply the formula to all columns. Basically, where you had a the column `F`, now we'll change it for a range on that row starting with `F`. For example, `F4` would become `F4:4`.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  REPT(
    ";";
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4; {$B$5:$B\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4; {$C$5:$C\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
    IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4; {$D$5:$D\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
    2
  )&
  VLOOKUP(
    F$1:$1&"-----"&F$2:$2;
    {ARRAYFORMULA(Fprod!$F$2:$F&"-----"&Fprod!$G$2:$G) \ Fprod!$H$2:$H};
    2;
    FALSE
  )
)
```

Notice that if you have data later in the spreadsheet, it will give you an error. You can remove it or set the maximum column.

Also notice that if the column doesn't have the proper data it gives us an error. We'll fix that later.

### Step 5: Split into columns

To split the representation into columns we need to use [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en). Split will split the values into a row. That means that we need to transpose ([see Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose)). So we should transpose, split, and transpose again. So let's add [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) and [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  TRANSPOSE(
    SPLIT(
      TRANSPOSE(
        REPT(
          ";";
          IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4; {$B$5:$B\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
          IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4; {$C$5:$C\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
          IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4; {$D$5:$D\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
          2
        )&
        VLOOKUP(
          F$1:$1&"-----"&F$2:$2;
          {ARRAYFORMULA(Fprod!$F$2:$F&"-----"&Fprod!$G$2:$G) \ Fprod!$H$2:$H};
          2;
          FALSE
        )
      );
      ";";
      TRUE;
      FALSE
    )
  )
)
```

### Step 6: Handle errors

There can be 3 cases we can handle:

1. The species and supplier was not found on `Fprod`
2. The batch does not exist
3. the column is empty

For the first one, we can simply add an [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) to the lookup, adding a default message. For the second we can add an [IFERROR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) wrapping [REPT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134?hl=en) because it will throw an error when the number is negative (when not found). And for the last one we need to use [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) with the value ";" when fails ([SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) requires the string to not be empty).

Adding all of that we we our final result:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  TRANSPOSE(
    SPLIT(
      TRANSPOSE(
        IF(
          (F$1:$1&F$2:$2&F$3:$3&F$4:$4)<>"";
          IFERROR(
            REPT(
              ";";
              IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4; {$B$5:$B\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
              IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4; {$C$5:$C\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
              IFERROR(VLOOKUP(F$4:$4; {$D$5:$D\ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A5:A)-5)}; 2; FALSE); -1) +
              2
            );
            "#Batch?  "
          )&
          IFERROR(
            VLOOKUP(
              F$1:$1&"-----"&F$2:$2;
              {ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(Fprod!$H$2:$H); Fprod!$F$2:$F&"-----"&Fprod!$G$2:$G;)) \ Fprod!$H$2:$H};
              2;
              FALSE
            );
            "#Species/supplier?"
          );
          ";"
        )
      );
      ";";
      TRUE;
      FALSE
    )
  )
)
```

If you remove any unnecessary white-space, you get the TL;DR formula.

### References

- [VLOOKUP (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en)
- [ARRAYFORMULA (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [SPLIT (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)
- [REPT (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134?hl=en)
- [TRANSPOSE (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en)
- [IF (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [IFERROR (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)
- [ROW (Google Docs Editors Help)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en)